# Point motion strategy for Emacs 25 and older

Tags: motion

I've read [What is inhibit-point-motion-hooks?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/what-is-inhibit-point-motion-hooks).

Assume some minor-mode `my-mode` that wants to do point-motion-y
things.

Assume `my--point-entered` and `my--point-left` functions that work
fine in Emacs < 25, when `my-mode` sets `point-entered` and
`point-left` props to use them.

Assume I'd like to have the mode keep working on Emacs < 25, but also
do the right thing if it finds itself on 25+. What is the right thing
to do?

I could `(setq-local inhibit-point-motion-hooks nil)` and call it a day. But that var is described as "obsolete", which seems stronger than
"deprecated". So that seems like not the right thing.

Is the following a good template to use instead?

```el
;; When mode is enabled
(when (fboundp 'cursor-sensor-mode)
  (cursor-sensor-mode 1))

;; When mode is disabled
(when (fboundp 'cursor-sensor-mode)
  (cursor-sensor-mode -1))

(defun my--cursor-sensor-function (window old dir)
  (let ((new (window-point window))) ;is this correct ???
    (pcase dir
      (`entered (my--point-entered old new))
      (`left    (my--point-left    old new)))))
;; where my--point-* are existing point motion functions

;; Where the props are added:
(let ((motion-props (if (fboundp 'cursor-sensor-mode)
                              (list 'cursor-sensor-functions
                                    (list #'my--cursor-sensor-function))
                            (list 'point-entered #'my--point-entered
                                  'point-left    #'my--point-left))))
  (add-text-properties beg
                       end
                       (append (list 'some-other-prop some-val)
                               motion-props)))
```

Or if that's not a good approach, what is the recommended way to work
with both older and newer versions of Emacs?

Comment: 1. Your second sexp overrides the first one: if `cursor-sensor-mode` is defined then the function is ultimately called with a `nil` argument. 2. Calling it with a `nil` arg or a `t` arg has the same effect, anyway. Use `1` and `-1` to turn it on and off, respectively.

Comment: @Drew Oops. I (thought I) already knew that detail about mode functions but managed to get that wrong in my example. Thanks!  I'll edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two systems work in fundamentally different ways, so you can't easily have a 100% solution that unifies the two, but your approach looks OK.  The only thing I'd recommend is to do the emulation the other way around: write your code for `cursor-sensor-mode` mostly and then write my-point-entered and my-point-left functions that call my-cursor-sensor-function.  The reason for that is that it is "optimized for the future" rather than "optimized for the past".

Comment: Thanks! I'll take your advice and reverse the emulation. Just to confirm, is it reliable to use `window-point` to get the `new` position (that's no longer provided as an argument); was that your intent?

Comment: Yes, `window-point` is what you want for that.

Comment: Sorry a follow-up point: I'm seeing `cursor-sensor-mode` work only when entering a region using forward motion. Backing into a region with e.g. `backward-char`, my cursor sensor function is not called. Is this as-expected, a bug, or a mistake on my end?

Comment: @GregHendershott: your description is not precise enough for me to decide if it sounds like a bug or a misunderstanding.

Comment: Actually the issue seems to be that c-s-m occurs one position sooner than a p-e when moving backwards. Something like treating the property `end` as inclusive vs. exclusive. Will report back with simpler recipe.

Comment: @GregHendershott: Whether point is considered "inside" or "outside" depends on the stickiness of the property.  For text-properties, stickiness of a property depends on the `front-sticky` and `rear-nonsticky` properties and for overlays it depends on the "front-advance" and "rear-advance" args that were passed to `make-overlay`.

Comment: Alas adding `'rear-nonsticky` with value `'(cursor-sensor-functions)` doesn't help. It seems [this expression in `cursor-sensor--detect`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/65eee8392ff95f58f7b0bd036e1fe065523658c6/lisp/emacs-lisp/cursor-sensor.el#L117-L118) is hardcoded to try looking back one more position regardless.

Comment: Hmm... indeed, according to the comment I didn't use the stickiness in the end, and instead I wrote the code so that if point is at either boundary it's always considered "inside".  So, indeed, the property's end is "inclusive", just like the property's start.  To the extent that `point` is always a position *between* characters whereas properties apply to the characters themselves, this should result in a "symmetric" behavior.  So I'm still not sure why/where you see an asymmetry in your tests.

Comment: It's awkward because my c-s-function uses `get-text-property` to find another prop -- but doesn't because _its_ `end` is treated as exclusive. It's also awkward when two c-s-m regions are adjacent, even with a space between them, the c-s-func is called as if they're one region.

Comment: I'm starting to feel that adding a `(setq-local inhibit-motion-hooks nil)` hack is my least-worst option short-term. :(  Maybe I need to do that as an initial fix, and loop back to using c-s-m later.